# Issue in Find in Python

Tags: python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have to find some text in String using list comprehension but not getting my expected result

```
A = "BANANA"

[[b,a[b:]] for b in range(len(a)) if a[b:][0].lower() in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'] and 'ANA'.find(a[b:])>=0]
```

I am getting the following result -

```
[[3, 'ANA'], [5, 'A']]
```

But my expectation is as follows:

```
[[1, 'ANANA'], [3, 'ANA']]
```

Please help me where is am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list comprehension is very close, however the issue is with the `if` condition which checks for a character starting with `A,E,I,O,U` and has to check if `ANA` is also a part of the entire string.

In your condition `if a[b:][0] in [....]` evaluated to True hence there is an output of `[5,'A']`. Since you have a condition which translates as

- Starts with a vowel in uppercase `AND`
- Contains `ANA` in the string

Your comprehension should instead be as follows:

```
[[b,a[b:]] for b in range(len(a)) if a[b:][0] in ['A','E','I','O','U'] and 'ANA' in a[b:]]
```

The result for `a='BANANA'` with the above comprehension is

```
[[1, 'ANANA'], [3, 'ANA']]
```

Hope it helps.